# Get jQuery version in WordPress via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm not sure if this is possible but I was hoping that I could retrieve WordPress' built-in jQuery version number programmatically via PHP.

I prefer to include a CDN version of jQuery using `wp_register_script()`, then I use the WordPress' built-in jQuery as a fallback.

The problem with using a CDN version is that if WordPress updates their built-in version of jquery, the CDN version might not match. So I was hoping to fetch the version number (maybe using `wp_default_scripts()`), and then pass that through to `wp_register_script()`.

Any ideas on how I get do this?

Comment: How about http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jquery-plus/. Seems that's what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I borrowed from [WP jQuery Plus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jquery-plus/):

```
function hs_script_enqueuer() {
    if( !is_admin() ) {

        // Enqueue so we can grab the built-in version
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        // Get jquery handle - WP 3.6 or newer changed the jQuery handle (once we're on 3.6+ we can remove this logic)
        $jquery_handle = (version_compare($wp_version, '3.6-alpha1', '>=') ) ? 'jquery-core' : 'jquery';

        // Get the WP built-in version
        $wp_jquery_ver = $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered[$jquery_handle]->ver;

        // Just in case it doesn't work, add a fallback version
        $jquery_ver = ( $wp_jquery_ver == '' ) ? '1.8.3' : $wp_jquery_ver;

        // De-register built-in jquery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');

        // Register CDN version
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'. $jquery_ver .'/jquery.min.js' );

        // Enqueue new jquery
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hs_script_enqueuer' );

// Add jquery fallback if CDN is unavailable
function jquery_fallback() {
    echo '<script>window.jQuery || document.write(\'<script src="' . includes_url( 'js/jquery/jquery.js' ) . '"><\/script>\')</script>' . "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'jquery_fallback' );
```

Comment: Hey, glad you found my plugin useful! Figured it might be better to just install [the plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jquery-plus/) so you're always up to date with anything new :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ! function_exists('register_jquery_script') ){

    function register_jquery_script(){

        /* Get jquery handle - WP 3.6 or newer changed the jQuery handle (once we're on 3.6+ we can remove this logic) */
        $jquery_handle = (version_compare($wp_version, '3.6-alpha1', '>=') ) ? 'jquery-core' : 'jquery';

        /* Get the WP built-in version */
        $wp_jquery_ver = $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered[$jquery_handle]->ver;

        /* Just in case it doesn't work, add a fallback version */
        $jquery_ver = ( $wp_jquery_ver == '' ) ? '1.8.3' : $wp_jquery_ver;

        /* the URL to check CDN accessibility */
        $url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' . $jquery_ver . '/jquery.min.js';

        /* test CDN accessibility */
        $test_url = wp_remote_fopen($url); 

        /* deregisters the default WordPress jQuery */
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); 

        /* if CDN available - load it */
        if( $test_url !== false ) {
            wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'. $jquery_ver .'/jquery.min.js', false , false , true );
        }

        /* if CDN unavailable - load local jquery copy */
        else{
            wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__, false, false, true);
        }

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','register_jquery_script');

}
```

you must be sure that you loaded local jquery into the **template_directory/js/** with name **jquery.min.js**

I'm loading all scripts in wp_footer() by default for page loading performance.
If you loading your js scripts in wp_header(), you will change the last **true** to **false** on lines:

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery' , $src , false , false , false );
```

Enjoy it!

Comment: while I like the *idea* of testing the URL this way, unfortunately need to point out that in this context it's not reliable as `wp_remote_fopen` will test your server's access to the CDN resource, *not* the user/client's access to it - so the script fallback method is actually more reliable because of this.